# Joda-Time strange hour

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I'm trying to initialise a [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object with the hour of 12:00 here is how I do this:

```
public static final long MINUTE         = 60 * 1000;
public static final long HOUR           = 60 * MINUTE; 

DateTime defaultDate = new DateTime(HOUR * 12);
System.out.print("the hour is: " + defaultDate.getHourOfDay()) // getting 14
```

Why I am getting 14 and not 12? Maybe Mama didn't teach me how to read clock right?!

Comment: Your question is unclear. You should explain what you were trying to do, what you expected, and what is wrong. Were you trying to create a date-time of noon on the first day of 1970 in your local time zone? That's what your code seems to suggest. I suggest you read the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) documentation and search StackOverflow for "joda" to find many examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're specifying a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, which was midnight *UTC*.

However, you're implicitly using the system default time zone in your `DateTime`, and I suspect that at the Unix epoch, your system time zone was UTC+2.

If you want to use a specific time zone, you can pass that in the constructor:

```
DateTime defaultDate = new DateTime(HOUR * 12, DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

Also, rather than using your own constants, you could either use `DateTimeConstants.MILLIS_PER_HOUR` or use [`java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) for conversions.

Comment: So is there any way to do this without the UTC?

Comment: @VladIoffe: Do *what* exactly? I suspect you haven't thought about precisely what type of object you're creating. If you want 12am of January 1st 1970 in your local time zone, I suggest you create a `LocalDateTime` first.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

Quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> **Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.**

### Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.EPOCH, LocalTime.of(12, 0)), ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1970-01-01T12:00Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Zjhc7Q)

**A couple of important notes:**

1. [`ZonedDateTime#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toString--) removes seconds and fraction-of-second if they are zero. If you want to display them, you can use `DateTimeFormatter` e.g.

```
String formatted = zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH));
```

2. The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### What went wrong with your code?

Quoted below the is description of [`DateTime(long)`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime-long-) with my emphasis:

Constructs an instance set to the milliseconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z using ISOChronology **in the default time zone**.

Your place, [Israel was at an offset of +02:00 hours in 1970](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/israel/jerusalem?year=1974) and therefore the `DateTime` instance was instantiated with an offset of +02:00 hours.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTime defaultDate = new DateTime(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(12), DateTimeZone.UTC);
        System.out.println(defaultDate);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1970-01-01T12:00:00.000Z
```

Another thing, which you might have already noticed from the code, is that DO NOT perform calculations yourself if there is already a standard API (e.g. `TimeUnit#toMillis`) available for the same.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>